# insert multi on a table handled by trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `md5_email` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `entered` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `country` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DE',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `md5_eml` (`md5_email`),
  KEY `entered` (`entered`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (uid)
(PARTITION id50k VALUES LESS THAN (50000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id100k VALUES LESS THAN (100000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id150k VALUES LESS THAN (150000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id200k VALUES LESS THAN (200000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION idOthers VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

& this trigger to check duplicate emails

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER checkExistEmail BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE md5_email = MD5(TRIM(NEW.email))) THEN
 SET NEW.md5_email = MD5(TRIM(NEW.email));
ELSE
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Email Already Exists';
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

the trigger works fine with single insert cmd

but with multi insert it stops when the first duplicate email found

how can i make it ignore duplicates without aborting all operation ?

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.21-MariaDB

Comment: You're better off just using a unique constraint instead of a trigger & `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: Indeed, you are right @Philᵀᴹ
unfortunately, for obvious reasons i cant change the table structure :(

Comment: "can't change the structure" -- This is unacceptable.

Comment: What is an "obvious reason"? I don't follow how you are allowed to add triggers (which can be and usually are messy) but not add a simple UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: I need to create partitions based on `uid`, if i add unique constraints to `md5_email` 
* ERROR 1503 (HY000): A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function *

Answer (score 0):

You have a contradiction -- On the one hand, you want to "ignore" dups.  On the other hand, you want to "SIGNAL" about dups.  Which is it?

If you want to signal after trying to insert multiple rows, you won't know which row(s) were dups.  If that is OK, then consider something like (I'm not sure of syntax):

```
DECLARE _dups INT DEFAULT FALSE;
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE md5_email = MD5(TRIM(NEW.email))) THEN
    SET NEW.md5_email = MD5(TRIM(NEW.email));
  ELSE
    SET _dups = TRUE;
  END IF;
  IF _dups THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Some Emails Already Exists';
  END IF;
END $$
```

Alternatively, you could probably use `rows_affected()` to see how many were successfully inserted.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James for your Answer, still have the same problem :(

Comment: I cant find a solution to ignore duplicates without raising exception, if i ignore signal it continue to insert duplicates without applying SET  *NEW.md5_email = MD5(TRIM(NEW.email));*

Comment: @lord13 why not just add unique index for table? it not change structure and not affect to other code. Than You just use INSERT IGNORE and  Forget about trigger?

Comment: Thanks @a_vlad for your suggestion
my table is partitioned by id, & if I add unique-index mysql return `A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

Comment: `PARTITION BY RANGE(uid)` is _totally_ useless together with `PRIMARY KEY(uid)`.  Get rid of partitioning; it will run faster _and_ you can add the `UNIQUE` key.